# How does the remote app operated machines work?

Tags: networking, dns

I just saw the iRobot commercial with the remote app functionality and now I am trying to figure out how that works. So I thought that maybe the robot in the house acts as a server on the home wifi network, but then I thought that running servers on many home internet plans is TOS violation, and how would they handle looking it up, especially considering that many home network connections have dynamic addresses. So how would it be handled?

Answer (score 0):

I think there will a third party service that will connect the robot with the owner. Both the robot and the owner will be registered on that service, where the robot will need to login to the service every time it powers up and the owner will need to login when he wants to remote control the robot. Then the service will find the robot that the owner owns and connect both of them. If you ever use "Team Viewer" application, the process is similar with it.

Comment: I wanted to know the technical details behind it. Not just something similar to it. More like how the sockets work.